# WPF - Оптимизация кода

Tags: c#, wpf

Необходимо оптимизировать захардкоженный код.
В программе работает всё хорошо, но код выглядит не красиво.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace KG
{
    public class Point
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
    }

    public class Lines : Point
    {
        public int Xstart { get; set; }
        public int Ystart { get; set; }
        public int Xend { get; set; }
        public int Yend { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Логика взаимодействия для LR1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Lr2
    {
        public int CountHorisontal;
        public int CountVertical;

        public int IdLabel;
        public int SizeX;
        public int SizeY;

        public Lr2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(30, 30, 30));
        }

        private void CreateLabel(int i, int j, string z)
        {
            IdLabel++;
            var dynamicLabel = new Label
            {
                Name = "label" + IdLabel,
                Content = z,
                FontSize = 10,
                FontFamily = new FontFamily("Times New Roman"),
                Margin = new Thickness(i, j, 0, 0),
                Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)
            };
            if ((string) dynamicLabel.Content == "0" || (string) dynamicLabel.Content == "-0") return;
            Grid.Children.Add(dynamicLabel);
        }

        private void CreateImage(int moveHorisontal, int moveVertical, int sizeX, int sizeY)
        {
            SizeX += sizeX;
            SizeY += sizeY;

            var wb = new WriteableBitmap((int) Img.Width, (int) Img.Height, 200, 200, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null);
            const int stride = 200;
            const int alpha = 255;
            var blue = 255;
            var red = 255;
            var green = 255;
            Int32Rect rect;

            byte[] blackColorData = {(byte) blue, (byte) green, (byte) red, alpha};

            for (var i = 0; i < 550; i++)
            {
                var horisontal = new Int32Rect(i, 175, 1, 1);
                wb.WritePixels(horisontal, blackColorData, stride, 0);
                if (i % 35 != 0) continue;
                CreateLabel(235 + i, 175 + 5, "" + i);
                CreateLabel(235 - i, 175 + 5, "-" + i);
                for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    var dashTop = new Int32Rect(i, 175 - j, 1, 1);
                    wb.WritePixels(dashTop, blackColorData, stride, 0);
                    var dashDown = new Int32Rect(i, 175 + j, 1, 1);
                    wb.WritePixels(dashDown, blackColorData, stride, 0);
                }
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < 340; i++)
            {
                var vertical = new Int32Rect(245, i, 1, 1);
                wb.WritePixels(vertical, blackColorData, stride, 0);
                if (i % 35 != 0) continue;
                CreateLabel(245 + 5, 165 - i, "" + i);
                CreateLabel(245 + 5, 165 + i, "-" + i);
                for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    var dashLeft = new Int32Rect(245 - j, i, 1, 1);
                    wb.WritePixels(dashLeft, blackColorData, stride, 0);
                    var dashRight = new Int32Rect(245 + j, i, 1, 1);
                    wb.WritePixels(dashRight, blackColorData, stride, 0);
                }
            }

            var a = new Point {X = 300 - SizeX, Y = 100 - SizeY};
            var b = new Point {X = 500 + SizeX, Y = 100 - SizeY};
            var c = new Point {X = 300 - SizeX, Y = 300 + SizeY};
            var d = new Point {X = 500 + SizeX, Y = 300 + SizeY};

            var firstLine = new Lines
            {
                Xstart = a.X + moveHorisontal,
                Ystart = a.Y + moveVertical,
                Xend = b.X + moveHorisontal,
                Yend = b.Y + moveVertical
            };

            var secondLine = new Lines
            {
                Xstart = a.X + moveHorisontal,
                Ystart = a.Y + moveVertical,
                Xend = c.X + moveHorisontal,
                Yend = c.Y + moveVertical
            };

            var thirdLine = new Lines
            {
                Xstart = c.X + moveHorisontal,
                Ystart = c.Y + moveVertical,
                Xend = d.X + moveHorisontal,
                Yend = d.Y + moveVertical
            };

            var fourthLine = new Lines
            {
                Xstart = b.X + moveHorisontal,
                Ystart = b.Y + moveVertical,
                Xend = d.X + moveHorisontal,
                Yend = d.Y + moveVertical
            };

            // Линия 1
            var n = Math.Max(Math.Abs(firstLine.Xend - firstLine.Xstart), Math.Abs(firstLine.Yend - firstLine.Ystart));

            var xA = new int[n];
            var yA = new int[n];
            xA[0] = firstLine.Xstart;
            yA[0] = firstLine.Ystart;
            for (var i = 1; i < n; i++)
            {
                xA[i] = xA[i - 1] + (firstLine.Xend - firstLine.Xstart) / n;
                yA[i] = yA[i - 1] + (firstLine.Yend - firstLine.Ystart) / n;
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                red = 155 + i;
                blue = 100;
                green = 100;
                byte[] colorData = {(byte) blue, (byte) green, (byte) red, alpha};
                rect = new Int32Rect(xA[i], yA[i], 1, 1);
                wb.WritePixels(rect, colorData, stride, 0);
            }

            // Линия 2
            n = Math.Max(Math.Abs(secondLine.Xend - secondLine.Xstart), Math.Abs(secondLine.Yend - secondLine.Ystart));
            var xB = new int[n];
            var yB = new int[n];
            xB[0] = secondLine.Xstart;
            yB[0] = secondLine.Ystart;

            for (var i = 1; i < n; i++)
            {
                xB[i] = xB[i - 1] + (secondLine.Xend - secondLine.Xstart) / n;
                yB[i] = yB[i - 1] + (secondLine.Yend - secondLine.Ystart) / n;
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                red = 155 + i;
                blue = 100;
                green = 100 + i;
                byte[] colorData = {(byte) blue, (byte) green, (byte) red, alpha};
                rect = new Int32Rect(xB[i], yB[i], 1, 1);
                wb.WritePixels(rect, colorData, stride, 0);
            }

            // Линия 3
            n = Math.Max(Math.Abs(thirdLine.Xend - thirdLine.Xstart), Math.Abs(thirdLine.Yend - thirdLine.Ystart));
            var xC = new int[n];
            var yC = new int[n];
            xC[0] = thirdLine.Xstart;
            yC[0] = thirdLine.Ystart;

            for (var i = 1; i < n; i++)
            {
                xC[i] = xC[i - 1] + (thirdLine.Xend - thirdLine.Xstart) / n;
                yC[i] = yC[i - 1] + (thirdLine.Yend - thirdLine.Ystart) / n;
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                red = 155;
                blue = 100;
                green = 100 + i;
                byte[] colorData = {(byte) blue, (byte) green, (byte) red, alpha};
                rect = new Int32Rect(xC[i], yC[i], 1, 1);
                wb.WritePixels(rect, colorData, stride, 0);
            }

            // Линия 4
            n = Math.Max(Math.Abs(fourthLine.Xend - fourthLine.Xstart), Math.Abs(fourthLine.Yend - fourthLine.Ystart));
            var xD = new int[n];
            var yD = new int[n];
            xD[0] = fourthLine.Xstart;
            yD[0] = fourthLine.Ystart;

            for (var i = 1; i < n; i++)
            {
                xD[i] = xD[i - 1] + (fourthLine.Xend - fourthLine.Xstart) / n;
                yD[i] = yD[i - 1] + (fourthLine.Yend - fourthLine.Ystart) / n;
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                red = 155 + i;
                blue = 100;
                green = 100 + i;
                byte[] colorData = {(byte) blue, (byte) green, (byte) red, alpha};
                rect = new Int32Rect(xD[i], yD[i], 1, 1);
                wb.WritePixels(rect, colorData, stride, 0);
            }
            Img.Source = wb;
        }

        private void CreatePicure(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CountHorisontal = -155;
            CountVertical = -27;
            CreateImage(CountHorisontal, CountVertical, 0, 0);
        }

        private void Left_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CountHorisontal -= 35;
            CreateImage(CountHorisontal, CountVertical, 0, 0);
        }

        private void Right_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CountHorisontal += 35;
            CreateImage(CountHorisontal, CountVertical, 0, 0);
        }

        private void Down_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CountVertical += 35;
            CreateImage(CountHorisontal, CountVertical, 0, 0);
        }

        private void Top_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CountVertical -= 35;
            CreateImage(CountHorisontal, CountVertical, 0, 0);
        }

        private void Increase_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CreateImage(CountHorisontal, CountVertical, 10, 10);
        }

        private void reduce_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CreateImage(CountHorisontal, CountVertical, -10, -10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы бы хоть картинку или гифку добавили как это все выглядит...но создавать элементы в коде почти всегда не есть хорошо.

Answer (score 2):

вполне приличный код. самое главное, что он понятен и его немного. Но если уж так хотите причесать:

- CreateImage можно разбить на несколько функций, считается что текст
  функции должен помещаться в экран
- Все Click-методы могу ссылаться на одну функцию
- Все координаты: 200, 235, 175, 340, 550 можно вынести в константы (скажем написать Width=550, Height=340, а остальные числа делать как Width-200 и т.д.). Это позволит сделать код более универсальным

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите выполнить рефакторинг, то можно проделать следующие шаги:

- изменение области видимости полей класса L1 на private (также можно
  добавить открытые свойства, если планируете использовать их извне)
- разбить метод CreateImage на несколько отдельных (довольно
  утомительно читать код метода длиною в 2-3 экрана)
- объединить методы-обработчики в одном методе (что-то вроде "InitializeHandlers"), который вы сможете инициировать (например, через конструктор)
- также, для удобства чтения кода возможно помечать определенные участки тегом *#region* (хотя, это может быть удобным не для всех).